# Context is not displaying in the template when using ListView

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I can't understand why nothing comes out in the html template.

```
class TrainersListView(ListView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'trainers.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        _list = Profile.objects.filter(city__slug=self.kwargs['slug']).order_by('id')
        context['trainers'] = _list
        print(len(context['trainers']) --> return 5
```

**html**

```
{% for trainer in trainers %}

{{ trainer.id }}
{% endfor %}
```

Even if I take out all the instances

```
_list = Profile.objects.all()
```

still a blank result
Am I doing everything right?

Comment: maybe you should use `return context['trainers']` ?

Comment: @furas you mean `return context`

Comment: That's right. What an unforgivable mistake! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot

```
return context
```

---

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    _list = Profile.objects.filter(city__slug=self.kwargs['slug']).order_by('id')
    context['trainers'] = _list
    print(len(context['trainers']) --> return 5

    return context
```

---

Doc: [Generic display views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/)